# Search multile words name in columns using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Is there any better solution to the code below, I want to search names but first name and last name is different columns as of now I have this

```
->where(function($query) use($q){
            $names = explode(" ", $q);
            if(count($names) == 2){
                $query->where('fname', 'LIKE', '%' . $names[0] . '%')
                ->where('lname', 'LIKE', '%' . $names[1] . '%');
            }
            else {
                $query->where('fname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%')
                ->orWhere('lname', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%');
            }
        });
```

but the result is only for firstname on the 1st array and the last name is on the 2nd array value, how would do it to make it sideways? or What if there is 2 words in 1st name and 2 words in last name?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

Firstly concatenate first name and last name then apply search on them.

`$result = User::where(DB::raw('concat(first_name," ",last_name)') , 'LIKE' , '%keyword%')->get();`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more flexible solution to search by first name and last name:

```
->where(function($query) use($q) {
    $name_wildcard = str_replace(' ', '%', $q);
    $name_wildcard = '%' . $name_wildcard . '%';

    $query->whereRaw('CONCAT(first_name," ",last_name) LIKE ?"', [$name_wildcard]);
});
```

Here, if you have a user in the table:

```
First Name: Juan Joseph
Last Name: Dela Cruz
```

If you search for `"Juan Cruz"`, it will show up

Answer (score 0):

Cody's answer should be accepted.  Only change I'd do is adding ability to do a quoted search function to match exactly and narrow results.

Something like:

```
if(preg_match('/^(["\']).*\1$/m', $search) == true){

$quoted = str_replace(array('"'), '', $search);

orWhere(DB::raw('CONCAT(firstname, " ", lastname)'), '=',  $quoted )
}else{

your other concat that is loosely searching

}
```